# How to ensure that a prediction will increase if a particular feature increases?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, prediction

I want to predict a value Y (numeric) using numerical features $X_1, ... X_n$.

I have a neural network (MLPRegressor in sklearn) that does a pretty good job at it (Adjusted R squared = 0.70), but I need an extra property: my prediction function should be increasing in the first variable if $ x_1'< x_1, prediction(x_1',x_2,...,x_n) \leq prediction(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) $. And that is often not the case with my neural network (in 30% of the cases that I have tested the prediction is superior)

In my case, $n=59$, my training dataset contains approximately 240 000 rows.

I know that to do that I would probably have to decrease the quality of my model (R2), and that is okay as long as it stays with a correct level. The only kind of model I see that is ensuring me that is a linear model but it does not fit my data very well (R2=0.31), though I admit I could do better feature engineering for the linear model.

As $X_1$ is independant from the other variables, I thought of doing a first prediction with a neural network (or RandomForest...) only using $(X_2,...X_n)$ as features to sum up all the info contained in the other features,  and then do a linear model with two features : $X_1$ and the prediction from my first model without $X_1$

Does it seem logical to you ? Thank you very much